# Context Menu items not flipping to RTL direction for Arabic language

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, contextmenu, right-to-left

I have added 3D touch gesture in my app on certain views to show information. In LTR language it's showing up as label on left side and Image on right side that's correct behaviour but while switching to RTL it's still showing in LTR way only. All other part of app is turned to RTL.

Here i am pasting simple code which i am using in app to display 3D touch.

Any help much appreciated.

```
.contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Button(action: {
                        //Do some action
                    }, label:
                            {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Copy ticket ID")
                            Image(systemName: "pencil.circle")
                        }
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        //Do some action
                    },
                           label:
                            {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Copy terminal ID")
                            Image(systemName: "paperplane.circle")
                        }
                    })
                })
```